# Lua detect a character/string repeated in all text

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I have several documents on a folder. Some of them, has this kind of text:

```
text="???????????????????????????????????? ??????????????????????? ?????????????????????????????????? ????????????? ???????????????????? ?????? ? ? ???? ????????????? ??????????? ????????????????????? ?????? ? ? ???? ????????? ?????????????????? ??????????????????????? ??????????? ????? ??????? ?????????????? ??????????????????????? ?????? ? ? "
```

I would like to recognize these documents and put this variable text like: `text=""`.

My problem is, how could I recognize this pattern? as you see, there are several "?" repeated with no identical number of repeats. The pattern should be "if there is no text and only "?" characters, delete content.

Comment: This looks like an artefact of not handling Unicode correctly. Is this an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: First Idea, something like this:
        string = string.find (text, "%w")
        print(string)

Comment: Thanks @Phylogenesis. I'm trying to solve it, but I'm worried about delete something I wouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the pattern `"[?%s]*"`, which means zero or more of `?` or whitespace characters.

```
if text:gsub("[?%s]*", "") == "" then
  -- do something
end
```